# What causes a "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement"

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, syntax-error

I'm new in VB, I am creating a program to connect ms access but when I run the program it gets

> Syntax error in Insert into statement, OleDbExpection was unhandled

Here's my code:

```
Public Class Form2

Dim cnn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection

Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    txtdate.Value = DateTime.Now
    cnn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0; Data Source=C:\Users\John\Documents\db.mdb"
End Sub
Private Sub btnsave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnsave.Click
    If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        cnn.Open()

    End If
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand

    cmd.Connection = cnn
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO sr(names,add,tel,dates,prob,serv,model,snm,acc,sna,remark)" & _
                          "VALUES ('" & Me.txtname.Text & "','" & Me.txtadd.Text & "','" & Me.txttel.Text & "', '" & _
                          Me.txtdate.Text & "','" & Me.txtpro.Text & "','" & Me.txtser.Text & "','" & Me.txtmod.Text & "', '" & _
                          Me.txtsnm.Text & "','" & Me.txtacc.Text & "','" & Me.txtsna.Text & "','" & Me.txtrem.Text & "')"

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    cnn.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

Is there any thing wrong with my code?

Comment: You're open for [Sql-Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx), use [`Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter.aspx) instead.

Comment: Please supply the real SQL error that you got. And please also state which DBMS you are using. PostgreSQL? Oracle? DB2? Try to print the generated SQL statement and post it here.

Comment: He's using an Access database backend (the provider was the hint to that, btw).

Comment: Why was this question marked as "not a real question"?  The OP does not know VB well enough to recognize where the problem is in his code (probably because it's a SQL error, not a VB error)...

Answer (score 4):

To make your code more readable and immune with `SQL Injection` use the following

- Command and Parameters
- use `Using` statement

snippet,

```
Dim comText As String = "INSERT INTO sr(names,add,tel,dates,prob,serv,model,snm,acc,sna,remark) " & _
                        "VALUES (@names,@add,@tel,@dates,@prob,@serv,@model,@snm,@acc,@sna,@remark)"
Dim connString As String = "ConnectionString Here"
Using conn As New OleDbConnection(connString)
    Using comm As New OleDbCommand()
        With comm
            .Connection = conn
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .CommandText = comText
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@names" , txtname.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@add" , txtadd.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@tel" , txttel.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@dates" , txtdate.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@prob" , txtpro.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@serv" , txtser.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@model" , txtmod.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@snm" , txtsnm.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@acc" , txtacc.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@sna" , txtsna.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@remark" , txtrem.Text)
        End With

        Try
            conn.Open()
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery
        Catch ex As OleDbException
            ' do something with the error
            ' don't hide it!
        End Try
    End Using
End Using
```

SOURCES

- [**AddWithValue**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx)
- [**Add** *(the recommended method to be used)*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add.aspx)
- [**OleDbCommand**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Your VB code is fine (it's not ideal as others have mentioned, but it's not buggy).

Syntax errors (and `OleDbExpection`'s in general) mean that the SQL string you have generated is invalid for your database.  To debug it, you'll need to view the generated SQL string before calling `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` and make sure it is valid SQL.

This error is *most likely* caused because you have invalid data in one of your input text boxes.  You can check them with simple `If ... Then` statements

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.txtdata.Text) Then
    'Add the txtdata parameter
End If
```